# Problems starting tomcat 7 in centos 7

Tags: java, tomcat, centos

I'm trying to run tomcat 7 in centos-release-7-4.1708.el7.centos.x86_64

These are the steps followed:

```
yum install java-1.7.0-openjdk-devel java-1.7.0-openjdk
```

Test if installed:

```
echo $JAVA_HOME
/usr/java/jdk/
echo $JRE_HOME
/usr/java/jdk/jre
```

Install tomcat 7

```
yum install tomcat tomcat-webapps tomcat-admin-webapps

systemctl stop tomcat
systemctl start tomcat
systemctl enable tomcat
```

It should create a symlink to tomcat.service, but no...

```
systemctl status tomcat


tomcat.service - Apache Tomcat Web Application Container
   Loaded: loaded (/usr/lib/systemd/system/tomcat.service; enabled; vendor preset: disabled)
   Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Mon 2017-11-13 10:26:33 WET; 4min 7s ago
  Process: 2825 ExecStart=/usr/libexec/tomcat/server start (code=exited, status=127)
 Main PID: 2825 (code=exited, status=127)

systemd[1]: Started Apache Tomcat Web Application Container.
systemd[1]: Starting Apache Tomcat Web Application Container...
server[2825]: /usr/libexec/tomcat/server: Failed to set JAVACMD
systemd[1]: tomcat.service: main process exited, code=exited, status=127/n/a
systemd[1]: Unit tomcat.service entered failed state.
systemd[1]: tomcat.service failed.
```

**UPDATE 1**

Content of file tomcat.service in /usr/lib/systemd/system

```
# Systemd unit file for default tomcat
#
# To create clones of this service:
# DO NOTHING, use tomcat@.service instead.

[Unit]
Description=Apache Tomcat Web Application Container
After=syslog.target network.target

[Service]
Type=simple
EnvironmentFile=/etc/tomcat/tomcat.conf
Environment="NAME="
EnvironmentFile=-/etc/sysconfig/tomcat
ExecStart=/usr/libexec/tomcat/server start
SuccessExitStatus=143
User=tomcat
Group=tomcat


[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

Answer (score 0):

Replace JAVA_HOME in the /etc/tomcat/tomcat.conf with /usr/java/jdk/

Comment: Hi. Replaced, still the same message

Comment: please check the path of Environment=TOMCAT_JAVA_HOME= in your tomcat.service file in /usr/lib/systemd/system/ then let me know

Comment: Edited with the info you asked me

Comment: Yes, same error. I will re-install the server and install from scratch!!, I'll be back if fails. thanks

Comment: if you want try this https://www.vultr.com/docs/how-to-install-apache-tomcat-8-on-centos-7

Answer (score 0):

I faced this case once after the server upgrade. I debugged into the script and it failed when checking if the java file is executable. So I had to change the ExecStart to something like this and it worked

```
ExecStart=/bin/bash /usr/libexec/tomcat/server start
```